# Is Java org.junit.Assert thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, thread-safety, assert

I want to verify if assert, and assertEquals is thread safe or not. I am under the understanding that it is not, as I believe I am running into race conditions wile using it for my JUnit tests. There are other ways I can go about verifying results of course. Its just simply out of convenience that I am using this function. I have looked at http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html for reference, and there's no mention of any internal synchronization, or locking. Thanks.

Comment: What is `java.org.junit.Assert`? I know of `org.junit.Assert`, but I haven't heard of `java.org.junit.Assert`.

Comment: my bad, its the same thing. I had appended java to the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any reasonable implementation, and the one I randomly googled, `assertTrue` and `assertEquals` are *thread-agnostic* themselves. Thread agnosticism is the usual state of the world.

For the values are changing then, for the `Object` overload, `equals` on the *expected* object will need to be thread-safe and necessarily the values from `toString` may be different.

The fail message is passed via a `String` to the simple `AssertionFailedError`, which all looks in order, although `Throwable` is not safe from *unsafe publication* (not much mutable is).